# Cgminer at Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, bitcoin

I'm following this tutorial to set up Ubuntu mining on Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gw7YPYgMgNNU42skibULbJJUx_suP_CpjSEdSi8_z9U/preview?sle=true

At last step they suggesting to check out settings with ./cgminer -n. I've got this

```
kirill@kirill-desktop:~/cgminer-2.11.4-x86_64-built$ ./cgminer -n

bash: ./cgminer: cannot execute binary file
```

What's wrong with me?

Comment: Doesn't work. Receiving -------> kirill@kirill-desktop:~/Downloads/phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6$ ./setup.pyusage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
Looks like it was a stupid idea to deal with those coins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a 64 bit cgminer on 32 bit ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a 32 (i686) bits version of the miner, in this case i'm not seeing on of those on the wget link

http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/